# IBOutlet says connected in StoryBoard, but not in code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, iboutlet

Not sure what the problem is here, I've tried:

1. Cleaning, rebooting Xcode/Computer
2. Clearing Derived Data
3. Relinking outlets

I don't have this problem with any other outlets in any other views. Here are some photos:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhht5.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxuIx.jpg

EDIT: It was a really silly mistake -> misspelled the identifier in my tableView method. Thanks for all your help though!

Comment: I think sometimes it just doesnt show visually, did you try using it? is it nil? is it crashing?

Comment: It crashes when I set the text of the label because it's trying unwrap and getting nil

Comment: I think you should provide more details then those two images alone probably aren't enough

Comment: Too many possibilities. Are you loading the cell correctly? It's in a storyboard, therefore you are using a `UITableViewController` right? You are not registering the cell manually right?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set your custom cell class in `Identity Inspector`?
[Identity Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBB5N.png)

Did you try delete outlet and drag outlet again?

Are you referencing to correct custom class? Double check this. I am often using another class unwillingly and than I realized that I am in wrong file.

Comment: This is not an answer... Questions belong in comments.

Comment: I would like to comment but I don't have enough reputation to do it. So this is only one way how can I help someone and gather more reputation. I'm sorry..

Answer (score 0):

I think its a normal behaviour, try loading your VC in the storyboard and add the assistant editor on the right. Mine does the exact same thing when i go to my code straight without loading the VC in the storyboard. Can you also show how you set the textLabel?